# QUERY NOT EXECUTED IN SQL (WHERE CLAUSE)

Tags: php, mysql

```
$courseArr = $this->query('
             SELECT  courses.*,modules.* 
             FROM courses 
             INNER JOIN student_courses
             ON student_courses.student_id = "'.$student_id.'" 
             AND courses.id=student_courses.course_id  
             INNER JOIN modules 
             ON modules.course_id=courses.id 
             AND WHERE courses.course_title like "$search%" ;
             ');
```

Comment: Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where courses.course_title like "$search%" inner join modules on modules.course_' at line 1

Comment: try with below answer

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$courseArr = $this->query('SELECT  courses.*,modules.* From courses inner join student_courses on student_courses.student_id="'.$student_id.'" and courses.id=student_courses.course_id  inner join modules on modules.course_id=courses.id where  courses.course_title like "'.$search.'%"');
```

you was using $search in ' single quotes. 
"semi colon" and "and" is also removed

Answer (score 2):

No need of `and` before `where`

```
$courseArr = $this->query('SELECT  courses.*,modules.* From courses inner join student_courses on student_courses.student_id="'.$student_id.'" and courses.id=student_courses.course_id  inner join modules on modules.course_id=courses.id where  courses.course_title like "$search%" ;');
```

Answer (score 0):

there is "and" before "where" condition, remove "and"

use this

```
"SELECT  courses.*,modules.* 
FROM courses 
INNER JOIN student_courses ON student_courses.student_id= '".$student_id."' AND courses.id=student_courses.course_id  
INNER JOIN modules ON modules.course_id=courses.id 
WHERE courses.course_title LIKE '$search%'" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
where  courses.course_title like "'.$search.'%" ;'
```

using above segment in your query insted of your.

```
WHERE courses.course_title like "$search%" ;
```

that is

```
$courseArr = $this->query('SELECT  courses.*,modules.* From courses inner join student_courses on student_courses.student_id="'.$student_id.'" and courses.id=student_courses.course_id  inner join modules on modules.course_id=courses.id where  courses.course_title like "'.$search.'%"');
```

Because $search is php variable and you need to concatenate and no need of and before whre clause

Answer (score 0):

No need of and before where

$courseArr = $this->query('SELECT  courses.*,modules.* From courses inner join student_courses on student_courses.student_id="'.$student_id.'" and courses.id=student_courses.course_id  inner join modules on modules.course_id=courses.id and where  courses.course_title like "$search%" ;');